# React Native and Tailwind: 'bg-green' is not a valid Tailwind class name

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, tailwind-css

I'm completely new to React Native and Tailwind but I've made a basic example:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native";
import tw from "tailwind-react-native-classnames";

const HomeScreen = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={tw`bg-green h-full`}>
      <Text style={tw`text-red-600 p-10`}>HomeScreen</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default HomeScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

I'm getting the error:

> 'bg-green' is not a valid Tailwind class name

When I remove the style for the SafeAreaView, the app works with no error which tells me that Tailwind is installed correctly. But something happens with that specific style that I can't figure out. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The only default colors for tailwind classes are white and black.
To set it green, you must refer to the tailwind-css page : https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors and select the green you need.

For your example, you can set the color to bg-green-500:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native";
import tw from "tailwind-react-native-classnames";

const HomeScreen = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={tw`bg-green-500 h-full`}>
      <Text style={tw`text-red-600 p-10`}>HomeScreen</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default HomeScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```